# What is predicate to use that contains a word

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate

Which predicate i need to use where objects in returned from Core Data array:

1. First objects must match completely;
2. Other object must just contained the specific word;

For example: 
I have entity Man(firstName:String, lastName: String).
Let's say, i have this objects in Core Data: 
1) Man(firstName: "John", secondName: "Alexandrov"), 2) Man(firstName: "Alex", secondName: "Kombarov"), 3) Man(firstName: "Felps", secondName: "Alexan").

And in returned arr i want to see [Man(firstName: "Alex", secondName: "Kombarov"), Man(firstName: "Felps", secondName: "Alexan"), Man(firstName: "John", secondName: "Alexandrov")]

How can i achieved this?

Comment: Do you want to filter the data, or to sort it?  A predicate can only achieve the former.

Comment: @pbasdf, do you mean that i can only get objects in random sequence, and  i cant sort them to a specific sequence in fetch request?

Comment: To sort the results when you fetch them, you must use NSSortDescriptor (not NSPredicate).  But CoreData is very restrictive: a fetch request can only be sorted according to an attribute value (or an attribute of a to-one relationship).  If you want a more complicated sort order, you will need to sort the array that is returned by the fetch request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `NSCompoundPredicate`.

First, you'd create a predicate for the `firstName`. This one would be strict, so you'd search for matches using `==`:

```
let firstNamePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", argumentArray: [#keyPath(Man.firstName), "alex"])
```

Then, you'd create a predicate for the `lastName`. This one is less strict, so you'd use `CONTAINS`:

```
let lastNamePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K CONTAINS[c] %@", argumentArray: [#keyPath(Man.lastName), "alex"])
```

Then you'd create an NSCompoundPredicate using the `orPredicateWithSubpredicates` signature.

```
let compoundPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: [firstNamePredicate, lastNamePredicate])
```

From there, you could create a `NSFetchRequest` and assign `compoundPredicate` as the predicate for the `fetchRequest`.

If you want to sort the results, you can add one or more `NSSortDescriptor`s to your `NSFetchRequest`:

```
let sortByLastName = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Man.lastName), ascending: true)
let sortByFirstName = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Man.firstName), ascending: true)
request.sortDescriptors = [sortByLastName, sortByFirstName]
```

Then, you'd do the fetch:

```
let request: NSFetchRequest = Man.fetchRequest()
request.predicate = compoundPredicate

var results: [Man] = []

do {
  results = try context.fetch(request)
} catch {
  print("Something went horribly wrong!")
}
```

Here's a link to a [useful post](http://nshipster.com/nspredicate/) on `NSPredicate`

Comment: it's close to truth! But i need to check: first: firstName == "Alex", secondName == "Alex". And then check firstName contains[c] "Alex",  secondName contains[c] Alex.

Comment: Adrian, with this predicates i got right objects, but my question is "Can i sort this objects to a specific sequence in fetch request?"

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but you can add sort descriptors (`NSSortDescriptor`) to your fetch request. I'll add a little on that to my answer.

Comment: ok, i will wait. I mean if that property(firstName or secondName) absolutely identical to some searchingTextString i want to see this object in the firsts positions in returned arr)

Comment: I dont' know if it possible

Comment: The scope of your question seems to be morphing. You can sort the results to put exact matches at the front of the array. Without tinkering with it, I'm not sure what the cleanest way would be to do what you want. You might post that as a separate question.

Comment: ty for time. As pbasdf says Core Data cant do this kind of sort, thats why i will try to sort returned array.

Comment: You could do two fetches. One for exact match, one for a "fuzzier" match. Then you could filter the the broader match array to entities that don't match  the exact match array and append the contents to the exact match array.

Comment: yeah. I found a solution!!!!!!! i dont use filter. I just make 2 predicates and 2 fetches. First with not complete coincidence. It looks like: "(firstName contains[c] %@ AND NOT(firstName LIKE %@)) OR (secondName contains[c] %@ AND NOT(secondName LIKE %@))". And second with complete coincidence. It looks like: "firstName == %@ OR secondName == %@". Could you please insert it in your answer to make it complete?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Adrian answer, I had to make couple changes for it to work.

```swift
    let FIRSTNAME = "Alex"
    let LASTNAME = "Smith"
    let firstNamePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "firstName == %@", FIRSTNAME)
    let lastNamePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "firstName == %@", LASTNAME)
    let compoundPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: [firstNamePredicate, lastNamePredicate])
    request.predicate = compoundPredicate
    do {
      results = try context.fetch(request)
    } catch {
      print("Something went horribly wrong!")
    }
```